# VS Cordova cannot connect to web service

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to make my first Visual studio Cordova app, I used angularJs to try to read a web service and I succeeded, but it failed when debugging that on the device, the application loads without the data from the service.

After some search, I knew that I needed to install the whitelist plugin, I did, but nothing. 
I also added this line to the config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

but still nothing.

I wish if someone would help me in that.

Comment: I made it work by adding connect-src to the Content-Security-Policy meta tag.

But I got another problem, when I debug on the device I get this:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem, 
For not connecting to the web service on my device, I only needed to add connect-src to my Content-Security-Policy meta tag.
you can also add the local host for testing on Ripple

```
connect-src http://yoururlgoesher.com http://localhost:*
```

for the other error, Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

I actually do not know what is the problem, I just started new project and copied the same exact code in this new project and it just worked fine with me.
If anyone has further information about this, please share.

Thanks